# Is it possible tests CSS stylesheets with Behat + Mink?

Tags: php, css, testing, behat, mink

Is there some way how to test css parameters (coming from css stylesheet) of some element? E.g. color of paragraph. Or background-color of div etc...

I know that selenium2 test framework can do this, but in Behat + Mink with selenium2 driver I cannot find a way how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would need to use Selenium2 driver along with Behat and Mink + custom JS calls to verify specific styles. The below example (Behat 3) uses jQuery to assert that the `div.myClass` `color` property is as expected. It sends script to Selenium, which evaluates it and returns the result, which you can process in PHP as usual.

```
<?php

class MyContext extends RawMinkContext
{

    /**
     * @Then /^The div.myClass color should be black$/
     */
    public function assertCssValue()
    {

        // JS script that makes the CSS assertion in the browser.

        $script = <<<JS
            (function(){
                return $('div.myClass').css('color') === 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
            })();
JS;

        if (!$this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily extend this into a more generic instance that will do all different kinds of assertions, but most logic will be in JS.

Besides there are other CSS testing frameworks / alternatives like [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS), which in theory should work with PhantomJS via Selenium Driver and Mink. Google "css testing framework" for that…

Comment: Hello, So many thanks, but in $script should be javascript without anonymous function. Here is more info: [link](https://github.com/Behat/MinkSelenium2Driver/issues/61)

Comment: It can, but Mink would add `return` statement if it doesn't start with `return` which often break things. With that in mind you can either start yours with `return` or make it so it doesn't break when the `return` is added. Above seems the most elegant approach.

Comment: I've started using Nightwatch.js which also can do BDD style assertions and uses selenium. I find it much better for checking front end stuff than behat. Helps that its all JS too.  You can see some examples in my package here: https://github.com/YoungElPaso/nightwatch-phantom-mcgill